# What is the definition of Loewy diagram?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I had seen an exercise:

> Write the Loewy-diagram of the direct indecomposable modules of the $A = K\Gamma / I$ algebra, where
>      \begin{align*}
>     \Gamma: 1  \underset{\beta}{\overset{\alpha}{\rightleftarrows}} 2 \underset{\delta}{\overset{\gamma}{\rightleftarrows}} 3, \quad
>     I = (\alpha \beta, \beta \alpha - \gamma \delta, \delta \gamma).
>    \end{align*}

Unfortunately I couldn't find the definition, or a way to compute, of Loewy-diagram.

Could someone point me to a resource explaining it?

Comment: This is actually a good question. You see the term Loewy-diagram often but I am also not aware of a formal definition in the literature. It probably just means the decomposition of the Loewy factors $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ into simple moduels of a module $M$.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat formal definition of the Loewy structure (which is the same as how Mare described, and I'm sure this is the Loewy-diagram you're looking for) can be found in [Benson's treatise](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-38940-7) in Lecture Notes in Mathematics. See [Appendix](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-540-38940-8%2F1.pdf), page 174.